# Backbone.js doesn't send request with model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have an application in rails 3 using backbone.js

When I use @model.save, i got an ajax call like this :

```
{"_id"=>"4fb8febe7d552d0a5e000010", 
"email"=>"toto@test.com", 
"invited_by_id"=>nil, 
"invited_by_type"=>nil, 
"role"=>"2", 
"id"=>"4fb8febe7d552d0a5e000010"}
```

I don't have my model name as key of my post parameters. I was expecting :

{ "user" =>

```
  {"_id"=>"4fb8febe7d552d0a5e000010", 
    "email"=>"toto@test.com", 
    "invited_by_id"=>nil, 
    "invited_by_type"=>nil, 
    "role"=>"2", 
    "id"=>"4fb8febe7d552d0a5e000010"
    }
```

}

How can i solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the role of [url & urlRoot](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url). Setting your model's `urlRoot` to say `/users` and configuring your server side routes accordingly does this job.

Comment: My problem was a rails problem. Sry for bad question.